# Lebesgue Integrable nonnegative function

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following problem to solve: Construct a integrable nonnegative function $f$ such that $f$ is essentially unbounded on any non-degenerated open interval $(a,b) \subset [0,1]$, that is for any set $E$ with $m(E)=0$, the function $f|_{(c,d)\backslash E}$ is unbounded. 
\
I have done the following: I have the function $f=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{2^k}\cdot \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{|x-x_k|}}$. I was able to show that is Lebesgue integrable since if I let $\{r_n\}=\mathbb{Q} \cap[0,1] $ such that $\int_0^1\dfrac{dx}{\sqrt{|x-r_n|}}$. Define $A_n=\dfrac{1}{2^n} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{|x-r_n|} }$ and $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n(x)$. By dominates converge theorem I get $f$ is Lebesgue integrable.

Now what I need is the idea or steps to prove essentially unbounded any help I would appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{x_n\}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$.

Define $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{2^k}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{|x-x_k|}}$ for $x\in[0,1]$.

**Essentially unboundedness:**

Let $(a,b)\subseteq [0,1]$, a non-degenerated open subinterval. Then there exists some $j\in \mathbb N$ such that $x_j\in (a,b)$. Note that every term in the definition of $f(x)$ is non-negative. Therefore, $f(x)\geq \dfrac{1}{2^j}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{|x-x_j|}}$. Note that $j$ is fixed and you can change $x$, which shows that $f(x)$ is unbounded in $(a,b)$.

Note that $m[(a,b)\setminus\mathbb Q]=m[(a,b)]$. So, for any $E$ with $m(E)=0$, the set $(a,b)\setminus E$ must contain at least one irrational number. Our argument above applies to this particular irrational number well. Hence, we conclude that   $f(x)$ is unbounded in $(a,b)\setminus E$, for any $E$ with $m(E)=0$.

**Integrability:**

Your argument with Dominated Convergence Theorem is somewhat problematic because you did not find a dominated function (which is necessary to apply DCT). So I decided to add one more short paragrah for proving the integrability of $f$ on $[0,1]$.

You may verify this with elementary Calculus: $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-x_k|}}dx\leq 2\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx.$$

Note that $f(x)$ is just an infinite sum of positive terms. Therefore, we can use Monotone Convergence Theorem to swap limits, which together with the inequality above proves the integrability of $f$ on $[0,1]$.

$\tag*{$\square$}$

Comment: Thanks for the help. I proved the inequality for integrability forgot to add it to what I wrote in the statement the problem initially had two parts and that was the first part. Thanks again.

Comment: @Thetexan Glad to help. If you found my answer was helpful, you might accept it, which would be an encouragement to me. Thanks :)